# How to add report to the right side bar in Openerp

Tags: odoo

I would like to add a link to a new report link for a product on the right side bar of OpenERP, but i don't know where is the view. I modified the addons/product/report/**init**.py to add my new report but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add report to the right side bar, you have to add `menu="True"` attribute in your report tag.

For example:

```
<report
    menu="True"
    id="my_report_id"
    string="My Report" 
    model="model_name"
    name="service.name" 
    rml="your_rml_path.rml"
    auto="False"
    header="False"/>
```

Comment: doesn't work with a working database, but if i create a new database, the new report appears. maybe i have to reinit the database, but how to do it ?

Comment: after a restart of the server with option --update=all, the report is visible, thanks